Single ended to differential conversion and back using op-amps
I have a single ended signal that I want to convert to a differential signal.
The single ended signal is a 0V - 1.8V rectified signal with a frequency of 16Mhz. To convert the signal a LMH6552 fully differential amplifier is used. For the conversion back to single ended a THS3062 is used. I am constrained by the board so that I can not use negative supply voltages. As a result both op-amps are supplied with 5V single supplies. 
The resistors of the LMH6552 are set so that gain is approximately 1 and to match a 50 Ohm system impedance as it was described in the datasheet of the LMH6552. 
The problem is that the Vout+ and Vout- signals are overlapping, so when the difference of Vout+ and Vout- is used in the reconversion process to single ended the result is a negative voltage, as you can see in this image. 
I would have expected a result like shown in the image below where the differential signals are centered around 2.5V, as the Vocm is set to 2.5V, and ranging from 1.6V to 3.4V.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Because of (asymmetrical) DC input coupling, a lot of problems arise:

Input signal source has zero impedance (Rs=0), is shorting RT out AC wise but develops a 0.9V DC offset across RT.
Resistor RM doesn't match the source input impedance (0 Ohm) of the other input and is grounded instead of having a similar DC offset.
Because the inputs are not balanced, the DC output voltages will differ. To make the DC levels of the two FDA inputs V+ and V- equal (~1.53V), the DC output levels have to deviate from the nominal offset of 2.5V and will be Vo+ ~ 2.77V and Vo- ~ 2.23V. Please note that the average of this two voltages is and has to be 2.5V (Vocm).
R6 = 100 Ohm is dispensable. I see no reason to make the situation for the FDA worse by loading the FDA with R6.
FDA outputs are DC coupled and not only have to drive an AC current but also quite some DC current (with VS3 = 0V) through the low value resistors of the second op amp.
The resistor values of the second op amp are way to low, especially R4.

As you have a single ended input and need a single ended output, why the use of a fully differential op amp?

[I'll hazard a guess about the R6.  The O.P. would know for certain.]  Possibly the R6 is termination resistance and there could be a cable between U1 and R6.  A long cable might be the reason for converting single ended to differential and back to single ended.

@NickAlexeev - Quite possible but as there is no info about any cable I have to stick to what is given. With a (100 Ohm) cable in-between the op amps the output impedance of the FDA should also be made 100 Ohm.
